# Xcode 10 lists more schemes compared to Xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode

When we run the command to list the schemes, Xcode 10 lists few redundant schemes as you can see, however, Xcode 9.2 lists only xxxx-iPad and xxxx-iPhone. These are the only two schemes we are interested in. Please help me understand why Xcode 10 lists more schemes. Thanks in advance.

```
env DEVELOPER_DIR=Applications/Xcode_10.app /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -list

xxxx-iPad;
xxxx-iPhone;
MZClockView;
Pods-xxxx-iPad;
Pods-xxxx-iPhone;
Pods-xxxx_iosTests;
Pods-xxxx_iosUITests;
xxxx_iosTests;
xxxx_iosUITests;



env DEVELOPER_DIR=Applications/Xcode_9.2.app /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -list

xxxx-iPad;
xxxx-iPhone;
```